# Batch Error : First error: Unable to write to any of the cursor

Tags: batch

First error:

> Unable to write to any of the cursor stores in the allotted time
>   (15000 msecs): took 15004 msecs for 24751 bytes, 0/3 succ/fail calls,
>   first fail: 598)

Getting the above error while executing batch can some one help to understand the reason behind this ?

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a know issue of Salesforce. It is related to Server Restart. The format of the message is similar to that you posted : 
First error: Unable to write to any of the cursor stores in the allotted time (15000 msecs): took xx msecs for xxxxxx bytes, 0/x succ/fail calls, first fail: xxx),
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008Y1YAAU
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008ZDlAAM
 Please mark 'This issue affects me' and you will be notified once Salesforce fixes this, alternately kindly reach out to support.